# Can one run Elastic Net with just one predictor?

Tags: r, regularization, elastic-net

I tried to run Elastic Net in R with just one predictor (don't ask me why).
It seems that, at least theoretically, it should be possible. I can run a regression with just one predictor and I might be overfitting - hence, I could reduce the size of the regression coefficient using regularization.
However, both 'glmnet' and 'caret' "told" me that I need at least 2 predictors.
Question: Why?
Or - if it's theoretically possible- what R or Python package allows one to do it?
Thank you!